# Facebook Batch Request: error (#100) Invalid parameter: Body of an error

Tags: facebook, batch-file

I need to make something simple as:

```php
$queries = array(array('method' => 'POST', 'relative_url' => '1665895414/apprequests', 'body'=>'message=hello'));
$jsonstr = json_encode($queries);   
$result = $facebook->api('/?batch=' . $jsonstr, 'post');
```

and the response is:

```php
[7] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => WWW-Authenticate
                        [value] => OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Invalid parameter: Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Invalid parameter"
                    )

            )

        [body] => {"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid parameter: Body of an error\/warning message. Title is: Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException"}}
    )
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it using this code (last question):

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/wiki/FAQ/008e2724c001374cee37887cc24d8cb9015adf6d

Comment: This link is no longer valid.  Care to update with a pointer to what "this code" actually refers to? :(